# Adding attributes to field_view_value

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using the following function to render a image field in a template, this works great but I would also like to add a custom `alt` attribute to the image:

```
function <module>_render_field($node, $field_name, $delta = 0, $display = array()) { 
   $field = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
   $field = field_view_value('node', $node, $field_name, $field[$delta], $display);
   return render($field);  
}

<module>_render_field($node, 'field_image', 0, array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(    
     'image_style' => 'object_380x250',
     'image_link' => 'content',
   ),
));
```

I was trying to add the `alt` attribute to the image by changing the above code to:

```
<module>_render_field($node, 'field_image', 0, array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(    
     'image_style' => 'object_380x250',
     'image_link' => 'content',
   ),
      'attributes' => array(
         'alt' => 'alternate'
      )
));
```

The above didn't worked but I managed to add the attribute by changing the module code to:

```
function <module>_render_field($node, $field_name, $delta = 0, $display = array()) { 
   $field = field_get_items('node', $node, $field_name);
   $field = field_view_value('node', $node, $field_name, $field[$delta], $display);
   // add alt attribute
   $field['#item']['alt'] = 'alternate';
   return render($field);  
}
```

I'm hoping there is a nicer way to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ideal case for using a preprocess in your template.php. You can use a [field preprocess](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/template_preprocess_field/7). Something like:

```
function THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  // do a dpm on $variables to see what you can use.
  $variables['items']['0']['#item']['alt'] = 'alternate';
}
```

You can also add a template file for your field. Check theme_hook_suggestion part in `template_preprocess_field` function for available theme_hook_suggestions. [Check this to see how you could use them.](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Edit: 
Here is a working code I tested:

```
// Here I use bartik as an exmample. You can change it to your theme name.
// First we add a preprocess to a certain field. The following is ONE way to allow 
// you to create   preprocess functions for any field. There might be better ways.
function bartik_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
// this will tell our theme system to look for preprocess's of the form
// THEME_NAME_field__field_FIELD_NAME.
$function = 'bartik_preprocess_field__'. $variables['element']['#field_name'];
  if(function_exists($function)) {
    $vars = $function($variables);
  }

}
// Then we change what needs to be changed.
function bartik_preprocess_field__field_nice_pic(&$variables) {
  // krumo($variables);
  $variables['items']['0']['#item']['alt'] = '123';
  // krumo($variables);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at it, you'll notice `MODULE_render_field` is not useful at all. Once you get the renderable array from `field_view_value` you can change the values in it and render it. If you're adding that to a template, it will look fugly, for sure. But it belongs in a preprocess call, where it will look just normal:

```
<?php

function MYTHEME_preprocess_SOME_TEMPLATE($vars) {
  $field_items = field_get_items('node', $vars['node'], $vars['field']['field_name']);
  $field_value = field_view_value('node', $vars['node'], $vars['field']['field_name'], $vars['field'][$delta], $display);
  // Alter the renderable array.
  $field_value['#item']['alt'] = 'alternate';
  $vars['altered_field'] = $field_value;
}
```

And in the template:

```
<div class="something">
 <?php print render($altered_field); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Still I would like to set the `alt` attribute to different values depending on the image, perhaps to the title of the node containing the field. What would be a good approach to do this?

Comment: Easier to show you with code, can you gist it?

Comment: What do you mean with "can you gist it"

Comment: http://gist.github.io

Comment: Can't you just edit your answer and add the relevant code?

Comment: Also, you link doesn't work?